# Change the relationship from @ManyToOne to @OneToOne

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, one-to-one, many-to-one

Is there a need to change the relationship from @ManyToOne to @OneToOne?

I mistakenly defined relation @ManyToOne instead of relation @OneToOne in my code

My classes in brief :

Class dev:

```
.
.
private long id;
private Com com;
.
.
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="S_COM_ID")
Public Com getCom(){
return com;}
.
.
```

class com:

```
private long id;
private String name;
.
```

After checking the database, I understood that the information is registered correctly. Do I need to change the relationship to  @OneToOne or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looking at the Java code provides me with no information about how the Database is set up.

Assuming the database is set up in the following way:

- You have a table `Dev` with the columns `id` and `S_COM_ID`
- You have a table `COM` with the columns `id` and `name`

Technically from a database standpoint multiple entries in `Dev` can reference a id in `Com`. Nothing in the database prevents them from doing so.

If you expect this, then I would suggest not changing the `ManyToOne` annotation, because in code and database it can happen, that multiple instances of the java class `dev` will result in the same (read `==`, not `Object.equals`) java `com` object.

If you do not expect this, then I would suggest changing your database structure to make it impossible for multiple entries in the `Dev` table to reference a single `Com` entry. The only way I would know to achieve this is to just move the `name` column from the `Com` table into the `Dev` table.

Comment: thank you. 
In my jsf page in entity 'dev' only one entry from entity 'com' can be selected. Is there still a need to change the relationship?  

That's why I ask this question that my program is running and if I need to change the program

Comment: If you have two dev rows, can you select the same com row?
If yes, keep the ManyToOne Annotation.
If it is not possible in the database, change it to OneToOne.

Comment: I checked in the dev table and saw how many dev rows can have the same S_COM_ID.    so we can say that a many-to-one relationship is the same as a one-to-one in the database?

Comment: In a true one to one relationship in a proper (normalized) database, a one to one relationship ensures, that it is impossible (even with manual db queries) to make a mistake and break the one to one relationship. This could be achived by having the primary key of dev = primary key of com.

Comment: In a Many to one relationship, that strong garuantee is not given.
Imagine that the S_COM_ID is stored as a integer. What is stopping you from doing a manual query and breaking the one to one relationship?

Comment: Database normalization basically means, that it is impossible with the relationships given to create a conflicting state.